# overlay UIView over AVPlayer - Swift - Programmatically

Tags: swift, overlay, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I have a `AVPlayer` which I set in this way:

```
fileprivate func setUpPlayer(_ videoURL: String, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let url = URL(string: videoURL)
    
    self.player = AVPlayer(url: url!)
    self.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    playerLayer.frame = view.bounds
    playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
    view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    player.volume = 1
    player.play()
    player.actionAtItemEnd = .none
}
```

I want to put a UIView which contains textViews and drawings over it but I don't know how to do it.

The ideal would be something similar to `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` with images

Comment: Add the player layer as a sublayer of the view with drawings (or in a view that is a subview of the view with drawings)

Comment: In that way I can export the entire video with the view embedded in it or just a frame? @AlexWalczak

Comment: Do you want the text view and drawings to be part of the video (like rendered with it)? Or just a simple overlay on top, which you can do with `addSubview()`?

Comment: The first thing you mentioned (rendered with it) @aheze

Comment: @StackGU This [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/6236502-avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos) is a great place to start